# Does bottle handle requests with no concurrency?

Tags: python, bottle

At first, I think Bottle will handle requests concurrently, so I wrote test code bellow:

```
import json
from bottle import Bottle, run, request, response, get, post
import time

app = Bottle()
NUMBERS = 0


@app.get("/test")
def test():
    id = request.query.get('id', 0)
    global NUMBERS
    n = NUMBERS
    time.sleep(0.2)
    n += 1
    NUMBERS = n
    return id


@app.get("/status")
def status():
    return json.dumps({"numbers": NUMBERS})


run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

Then I use jmeter to request `/test` url with 10 threads loops 20 times.

After that, `/status` gives me `{"numbers": 200}`, which seems like that bottle does not handle requests concurrently.

Did I misunderstand anything?

**UPDATE**

I did another test, I think it can prove that bottle deal with requests one by one(with no concurrency). I did a little change to the `test` function:

```
@app.get("/test")
def test():
    t1 = time.time()
    time.sleep(5)
    t2 = time.time()
    return {"t1": t1, "t2": t2}
```

And when I access `/test` twice in a browser I get:

```
{
    "t2": 1415941221.631711,
    "t1": 1415941216.631761
}
{
    "t2": 1415941226.643427,
    "t1": 1415941221.643508
}
```

Comment: `200` is HTTP Code for OK signal http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: @Lafada Oh, let me make it more clear, `/status` gives me `{"numbers": 200}`

Comment: now we can give proper answer :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Concurrency isn't a function of your web framework -- it's a function of the web server you use to serve it. Since Bottle is WSGI-compliant, it means you can serve Bottle apps through any WSGI server:

- wsgiref (reference server in the Python stdlib) will give you no concurrency.
- CherryPy dispatches through a thread pool (number of simultaneous requests = number of threads it's using).
- nginx + uwsgi gives you multiprocess dispatch *and* multiple threads per process.
- Gevent gives you lightweight coroutines that, in your use case, can easily achieve C10K+ with very little CPU load (on Linux -- on Windows it can only handle 1024 simultaneous open sockets) if your app is mostly IO- or database-bound.

The latter two can serve massive numbers of simultaneous connections.

According to http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html , when given no specific instructions, `bottle.run` uses wsgiref to serve your application, which explains why it's only handling one request at once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The other day I was asked about bottle concurrency problem at a interview, wish I have read this before.