# Multiprocessing Python Bottle Multiple Commands independent of a running pool.apply_async

Tags: python, bottle, python-multiprocessing

The Problem, I made a rest api out of bottle to start Elasticsearch bulk loads. The bulk load process runs inside of a multiprocess pool, the problem is while that is running the api wont except any other commands.

I've even tried running another instance of the api on a different port but I have stack question about that too. The second one doesn't accept commands.

I want to be able to call a different api command to get the status of the load and return it. Currently it just includes ES data, but eventually its going to include each nodes stats. This is designed to run from Jenkins and initiate parallel loads.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Copyright [current year] the Melange authors.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
# 
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# 
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.exceptions import RequestError
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, pool
from datetime import datetime
import boto3
import sys
import os
import argparse
import logging
import logging.config
from bottle import route, run
from boto.cloudformation.stack import Output
import json

#this is what is called to set up the loading process from the api.    
def start_load(secret, access, protocol, host, ports, index, type, mapping, data,threads):

    # decompress a gzip string
    def decompress_gzip(data):
        return Popen(['zcat'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE).communicate(input=data)[0]

    # parse an s3 path into a bucket and key 's3://my-bucket/path/to/data' -> ('my-bucket', 'path/to/data')
    def parse_s3_path(str):
        _, _, bucket, key = str.split('/', 3)
        return (bucket, key)

    def shell_command_execute(command):
        p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
        (output, err) = p.communicate()
        return output

    # load an S3 file to elasticsearch 
    def load_s3_file(s3_bucket, s3_key, es_host, es_port, es_index, es_type, access, secret):
        try:
            logging.info('loading s3://%s/%s', s3_bucket, s3_key)
            s3 = boto3.client('s3',  aws_access_key_id=access, aws_secret_access_key=secret)
            file_handle = s3.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_key)
            file_contents = file_handle['Body'].read()
            logging.info('%s'%s3_key)
            if file_contents:
                if s3_key.endswith('.gz'):
                    file_contents = decompress_gzip(file_contents)
                es = Elasticsearch(host=es_host, port=es_port, timeout=180)
                es.bulk(body=file_contents, index=es_index, doc_type=es_type, timeout=120)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("There has been a major error %s" % e)

    # load an S3 file to elasticsearch
    def load_single_s3_file(s3_bucket, s3_key, es_host, es_port, es_index, es_type, access, secret):
        try:
            logging.info('loading s3://%s/%s', s3_bucket, s3_key)
            s3 = boto3.client('s3',  aws_access_key_id=access, aws_secret_access_key=secret)
            file_handle = s3.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_key)
            file_contents = file_handle['Body'].read()
            logging.info('%s'%s3_key)
            if file_contents:
                if s3_key.endswith('.gz'):
                    file_contents = decompress_gzip(file_contents)
                es = Elasticsearch(host=es_host, port=es_port, timeout=180)
                res = es.get(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1)
                es.insert(body = file_contents, index = es_index, doc_type=es_type, timeout=120)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("There has been a major error %s" % e)

    start = datetime.now()
    es_url = protocol + '://' + host + ':' + str(ports) + '/' + index + '/' + type
    es = Elasticsearch(host=host, port=ports, timeout=180)

    # S3 file - https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object
    s3 = boto3.client('s3',  aws_access_key_id=access, aws_secret_access_key=secret)
    s3_bucket, s3_key = parse_s3_path(mapping)
    file_handle = s3.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_key)
    mapping = file_handle['Body'].read()

    try:
        es.indices.create(index=index, body=mapping)
    except:
        logging.error('index exist')

    logging.info('starting to load %s to %s', data, es_url)
    es.indices.put_settings({'index': {'refresh_interval': '-1'}}, index=index)  

    pool = Pool(processes=int(threads))

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=access, aws_secret_access_key=secret)
    s3_bucket, s3_key = parse_s3_path(data)

    for file_summary in s3.Bucket(s3_bucket).objects.all():
        if file_summary.key.startswith(s3_key):
            pool.apply_async(load_s3_file, args=(s3_bucket, file_summary.key, host, ports, index, type, access, secret))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    es.indices.put_settings({'index': {'refresh_interval': '1s'}}, index=index)
    logging.info('finished loading %s to %s in %s', data, es_url, str(datetime.now() - start))
    sys.exit(0)
    #reset_es_settings(host, ports)
#This is what is called when no arguments are given

@route('/load_data/')
def no_comands():
    return """Please include all nessecary values: example: 
                Start Load
                http://127.0.0.1:8001/load_data/load&host=ip or DNS&thread=5&mappinglocation=tr-ips-ses-data|mappings|version_1_2|wos.mapping&datalocation=tr-ips-ses-data|json-data|wos|20150724|wos-1&port=9200&index=wos4&protocol=http&type=wos&access=access_key&secret=secret_key
                Delete Index
                http://127.0.0.1:8001/delete/wos4&host=ip or DNS&port=9200

                with loading you must specify the load command as shown above
                use & to seperate values
                use = to seperate key value pairs
                use | to insert \
                """

@route('/load_data/<name>', method='GET')
def commands( name="Execute Load" ):

    values = name.split('&')
    #split apart the url syntax items are split by & key values by = and any plcae that needs \ gets |
    try:
        command = values[0]
        host = values[1] + ".us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com"
        threads = values[2]
        mapping_location = values[3].replace('|', '/')
        data_location = values[4].replace('|', '/')
        #mapping_location = values[3]
        #data_location = values[4]
        ports = values[5]
        index = values[6]
        protocol = values[7]
        type = values[8]
        access = values[9]
        secret = values[10]

        host = host.split('=')[1]
        threads = threads.split('=')[1]
        mapping_location = "s3://" + mapping_location.split('=')[1]
        data_location = "s3://" + data_location.split('=')[1]
        ports = ports.split('=')[1]
        index = index.split('=')[1]
        protocol = protocol.split('=')[1]
        types = type.split('=')[1]
        access = access.split('=')[1]
        secret = secret.split('=')[1]

        yield ("Starting Load of data use /get_status/es_url&es_port&index to get the status of your load.")
        start_load(secret, access, protocol, host, ports, index, types, mapping_location, data_location,threads)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        yield   """Please include all nessecary values: example: 
                Start Load
                http://127.0.0.1:8001/load_data/load&host=ip or DNS&thread=5&mappinglocation=tr-ips-ses-data|mappings|version_1_2|wos.mapping&datalocation=tr-ips-ses-data|json-data|wos|20150724|wos-1&port=9200&index=wos4&protocol=http&type=wos&access=access_key&secret=secret_key
                Delete Index
                http://127.0.0.1:8001/delete/wos4&host=ip or DNS&port=9200

                with loading you must specify the load command as shown above
                use & to seperate values
                use = to seperate key value pairs
                use | to insert \
                """

#This is what is cvalled when /delete/ is used.
@route('/delete/<name>', method='GET' )
def recipe_delete( name="Delete Index" ):

    def shell_command_execute(command):
        p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
        (output, err) = p.communicate()
        return output

    values = name.split('&')
    try:
        #split apart the url syntax items are split by & key values by |
        index = values[0]
        host = values[1] + ".us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com"
        host = host.split('=')[1]
        port = values[2]
        port = port.split('=')[1]
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return """Please include all nessecary values: example: 
                Start Load
                http://127.0.0.1:8001/load_data/load&host=ip or DNS&thread=5&mappinglocation=tr-ips-ses-data|mappings|version_1_2|wos.mapping&datalocation=tr-ips-ses-data|json-data|wos|20150724|wos-1&port=9200&index=wos4&protocol=http&type=wos&access=access_key&secret=secret_key
                Delete Index
                http://127.0.0.1:8001/delete/wos4&host=ip or DNS&port=9200

                with loading you must specify the load command as shown above
                use & to seperate values
                use = to seperate key value pairs
                use | to insert \
                """

    try:     
        #This is the command that deletes the index.     
        curl_command = 'curl -XDELETE http://' + host + ':9200/' + index     
        shell_command_execute(curl_command)
        return "Successfully Deleted Index"
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return "Failed to Deleted Index %s" % e

if __name__ == '__main__':

    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
    url = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/logging.ini'
    print url
    logging.config.fileConfig(url)
    run(host='172.31.28.189', port=8001, debug=True)
    #run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8001, debug=True)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does bottle handle requests with no concurrency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923101/does-bottle-handle-requests-with-no-concurrency)

Comment: See details inside the link above - it seems that bottle can handle only one request at a time.

Comment: Please read Bottle's [Primer to Asynchronous Applications](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html).